# I am unable to show "X" button in JDialog box in java

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

[image]

I have created JDialog box which does not show `"X"`, minimize and maximize button and it shows title set. I have not used `setUndecorated(true);`

does I have set any property that hides this buttons ?

I have added image of JDialog which does not me close, minimize, maximize button.

```
package com.example;

public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJDialog
     */
    public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Search Patients");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the dialog
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the effect you describe.

Comment: I hope you not using `JWindow` and calling it `JDialog` :-)

Comment: `I am using JDialog` so post your `MCVE`, that shows your demo code causing this problem.

Comment: @camickr I have posted my code which does not show me close "X" button in jdialog, I am using linux for creating application

Comment: If parent is set to null, I would expect a close button. `setResizable(true)` might help. There are several ModalityType-s you may try.

Comment: I am passing parent as this i.e current jframe from which it is called and I have tried modality types also.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the parent from constructor ? I have the same problem, if the parent is null the close button is now available... (seen on linux, not on win 7)